# Lampp on Ubuntu - httpd.conf

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, lampp

Hey, I've got Lampp installed in Ubuntu and I want to get .htaccess working but I don't know how. And, yes, I have searched all over google.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `AllowOverride None` directives, as that's what would tell Apache not to look for `.htaccess` files.

Comment: So once I've found that what should I do?

Comment: Change or remove the directive. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride